# Upload files from fontend into WP categories

Tags: wordpress

i have searched a lot, not comming up with a solution, i want to allows department users in organization to be able to upload files from frontend in Wordpress, they should be able to upload into there category, like i have created Legal Post category, so legal guys should upload only to legal category,

any plugin or file manager for wp

thanks

Answer (score 1):

we have hook 'edit_category_form_fields' for add extra field in the post category. which will help you for set upload field for upload file. Once it field is create then we have to set permission for this field to able to add from front-end. Please check this link how to use hook the help you. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_category_form_fields/